# Intersect and exists performance Oracle11g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, exists, intersect

I would like to know whether `INTERSECT` or `EXISTS` have better performance in `Oracle 11g`. Consider I have the below two tables.

**Student_Master**

```
STUDENT_ID   NAME
----------  ------
STUD01       ALEX
STUD02       JAMES
STUD03       HANS
```

**Student_Status**

```
STUDENT_ID   STATUS
----------  ------
STUD01       Fail
STUD02       Pass
STUD03       Pass
```

Which of the below query will perform better considering that the table **Student_Status** will have more number of records compared to the table **Student_Master**.

```
SELECT STUDENT_ID FROM Student_Master
INTERSECT
SELECT STUDENT_ID FROM Student_Status

SELECT STUDENT_ID FROM Student_Master M
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT STUDENT_ID FROM Student_Status S WHERE M.STUDENT_ID=S.STUDENT_ID)
```

Comment: Did you try to compare explain plans?

Comment: Either could be faster, or they could be the same.

Comment: Better performance in 11g than what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick test would suggest the EXISTS option...

```
SELECT STUDENT_ID FROM Student_Master INTERSECT SELECT STUDENT_ID FROM
Student_Status

Plan hash value: 416197223

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation             | Name             | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT    |                    |       |       |     6 (100)|          |
|   1 |  INTERSECTION         |                  |       |       |              |            |
|   2 |   SORT UNIQUE         |                  |     3 |    36 |     3  (34)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| STUDENT_MASTER |     3 |    36 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |   SORT UNIQUE         |                  |     3 |    36 |     3  (34)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| STUDENT_STATUS |     3 |    36 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

-

```
SELECT STUDENT_ID FROM Student_Master M WHERE EXISTS (SELECT STUDENT_ID
FROM Student_Status S WHERE M.STUDENT_ID=S.STUDENT_ID)

Plan hash value: 361045672

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation      | Name       | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |            |       |       |     4 (100)|      |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN SEMI    |            |     3 |    72 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| STUDENT_MASTER |     3 |    36 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| STUDENT_STATUS |     3 |    36 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks BobC. Great answer

Answer (score 0):

The second form with EXIST operator does always full scan on Student_Master table, so I think, you'll get better performance using intersect. But you'll need use index on master table.

More info on EXIST can be found here: [Ask TOM - IN & EXISTS](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::p11_question_id:953229842074)